# How to add dynamic width and color to a view in react native?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to adjust the width of a view and color according to a variable. I initially declare the variable inside the app which doesnt seem to work. I have also tried declaring the variable outside the function scope but doesnt register. Is there anyway I could dynamically edit the width of the child using the declared variable? Or is there a function that allows me to do this?

```
const app = () =>{

const childWidth = 50;
const viewColor = 'red'

return(


<View style={styles.parent}> 
 <View style={styles.child}>CHILD</View>
</View>
)}

styles = styleSheet.create({
 parent:{
 width: 100,
 color: 'white',
 },
 child:{
 width: {childWidth},
 color: {viewColor},
 }

})
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to edit the width dynamically so let's change it using an InputText.

first let's create our useState hook.

```
const myFunc = () =>{
const [width , setWidth] = useState("50px")

return(
<>
<TextInput onChangeText={setWidth}
        value={width} />

//let's assume you want to change the width of this element.

<element style={{width : {width} }}

</>
)
```

export default ...

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you can use styles in condition

```
const app = () =>{
    const isChildOneStyle = true
return(
  <View style={styles.parent}> 
     <View style={isChildOneStyle ? styles.child1 : styles.child2}>CHILD</View>
</View>
)}

styles = styleSheet.create({
 parent:{
 width: 100,
 color: 'white',
 },
 child1:{
 width: 50,
 color: 'red',
 },
child2:{
 width: 80,
 color: 'green',
 },

})

or you can overrite style

const app = ({customStyles}) =>{

return(
<View style={styles.parent}> 
 <View style={[styles.child, customStyles]}>CHILD</View>
</View>
)}
```

or if you retreived this parameters from api you can do like this

```
const app = ({customWidth, customColor}) =>{

return(
<View style={styles.parent}> 
 <View style={[styles.child, { width :customWidth , color: customColor }]}>CHILD</View>
</View>
)}
```

Comment: I need the variable to be the width. This snippet is from a wider code base where the width variable is a piece of data retrieved from an api

Comment: I corrected example for you :) i hope it helps

Comment: I see youve added square brackets to the styles.child and included width and color as 2nd/ 3rd style parameters.. I have tried this but doesnt seem to work. It has a red underline underneath :